Can I turn off EF Core foreign key mapping?
I've got a non-standard foreign key situation in my SQLite database and I don't control the schema to change it. There is a parent table that has a FK to a child table, but the FK is to a column that isn't the primary key of the child table.
We have:
Parent       Child
______       ______
Id           Id
...columns   ...columns
ExternalId
ChildId  --> ExternalId

And this is modeled in EF POCO's as:
class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ExternalId { get; set; }
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public Child Child { get; set; }
}

class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ExternalId { get; set; }
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
}

My app gets parent/child data from a Web API request and these entities have an ExternalId from the remote server. We serialize these to a local SQLite database in which Parent.Id and Child.Id are primary keys that are auto-incremented and we want Parent.ChildId == Child.ExternalId. Yes, I know this isn't good normal form, but I can't change it.
Parent.ChildId is provided by the external service and I do not want it to be set in EF, but no matter what I do, when I try to add a Parent object to the data context, EF is setting Parent.ChildId to some auto-incremented value, instead of leaving it alone.
This is true even when I remove ALL [ForeignKey] attributes.
I cannot find any combination of attributes or fluent API calls that will handle the ChildId FK correctly. It seems like EF Core always assumes that I want it to set ChildId, and then this blows up when I try to add the parent object to the database.
Is there any way to get the behavior that I need?

You can use the fluent API to configure relationship:
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Child>()
     .HasIndex(c => c.ExternalId)
     .IsUnique(); // ExternalId should be a PK or unique index

    modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
      .HasOne(p => p.Child)
      .WithMany()
      .HasForeignKey(nameof(Parent.ChildId))
      .HasPrincipalKey(nameof(Child.ExternalId));
}

Which results in the following Parents table created:
CREATE TABLE "Parents" (
    "Id" INTEGER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "PK_Parents" PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "ExternalId" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "ChildId" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "FK_Parents_Children_ChildId" FOREIGN KEY ("ChildId") REFERENCES "Children" ("ExternalId") ON DELETE CASCADE
);

P.S.
I would argue that your terminology is a bit reversed, if Parent references Child then it is actually a child table.

What it sounds like is your issue isn't the FK, it is the fact that the FK is pointing to this ExternalId while you have assigned a new, arbitrary PK column. (Id) Foreign keys normally point to the PK.
The simplest thing would be to just accept that these tables will be "owned" by the external system where the external Id is the PK. I don't see how you gain anything by adding an arbitrary auto-increment column to serve as a PK if it isn't going to be used for relationships, or having some relationships use the Id while others rely on the ExternalId.
Alternatively you can explicitly set up the relationships to use the ExternalId as the principal side of the relationship:
modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
    .HasOne(x => x.Child)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<Parent>(x => x.ChildId)
    .HasPrincipalKey<Child>(x => x.ExternalId);


This is very helpful, thanks. AFAICT, HasForeignKey requires a string array argument and when I try the generic syntax in your example, I get the error The non-generic method 'ReferenceCollectionBuilder<Parent, Child>.HasForeignKey(params string[])' cannot be used with type arguments. Are you using a non-standard extension method here? If so, can you share it?

Hmm, no, there should be two main flavours of HasForeignKey, one that takes an expression and one that takes a params string array.  If you use the string variant and then select the method and go to Definition, where does it end up? With EF Core it should be the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore assembly, namespace Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders; It should be going to a ReferenceReferenceBuilder, for Parent.Child, not a ReferenceCollectionBuilder Your real-world entities are likely differing critically from your example.
